# Error Connecting Node-Ubuntu Droplet to Meteor Galaxy Server Over DDP

Tags: node.js, meteor, ubuntu-14.04, digital-ocean, ddp

I am trying to connect a node server hosted on a Digital Ocean-Ubuntu machine to my Meteor server hosted on Galaxy over DDP.

This node server handles some of the CPU heavy server tasks, but the jobs that it does the work for are created on my Meteor server. So, the two servers must communicate over DDP.

This works fine when I have my node server run on my local machine and connect to my Galaxy-hosted Meteor server. However, once I move my node server to DO and try to run the same code, I get a connection timeout error.

Any idea why this would happen when trying to connect from DO?